# Moved wordpress with woocommerce: get_gallery_attachment_ids() thumbs not showing

Tags: php, mysql, image, wordpress

I'm attempting to move a Wordpress site (currently hosted by a foreign, difficult to deal with web development company,) to another server before they shut it down. I have access to wp-admin but no cpanel or ftp, and there are memory limitations which have prevented me from using a complete duplication/migration plugin.

Most of my regular work is HTML/CSS and I have very little experience with SQL and PHP, but I have managed to get the site copied in bits and pieces and reassembled on my local machine. It's functioning as expected except for one niggling issue I've been unable to resolve.

*The woocommerce product page is displaying the main image as expected, but the product gallery thumbs are coming up empty;*
[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSuOP.png)

The code which should be presenting the images is:

```
<!-- first image is viewable to start -->
<?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </div>
<div class="previews">
       <?php 
       $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
       foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
          $sql="select guid from wp_posts where ID=".$attachment_id;
          $row=mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query($sql));
       ?>
      <a data-full="<?php echo $row->guid;?>"><img src="<?php echo $row->guid;?>" width="56" height="58" /></a>
       <?php }
       ?>
        </div>
```

When I view the page source the img src literally is empty;

```
<a data-full=""><img src="" width="56" height="58" /></a>
<a data-full=""><img src="" width="56" height="58" /></a>
<a data-full=""><img src="" width="56" height="58" /></a>
<a data-full=""><img src="" width="56" height="58" /></a>
<a data-full=""><img src="" width="56" height="58" /></a>
```

Unfortunately I'm pretty clueless with SQL, which I'm assuming is the source of the problem? The same code works fine on the original site, which has been copied exactly (in theory) and the images that are supposed to be showing are present in the "product gallery" panel when editing the product. Adding a new image results in the same problem. Other images on the site seem to be working OK.

Any advice on what might be going on and how I might correct this error would be greatly appreciated!

Edited to add: [screencap of product edit page, shows the thumbnails that should be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A45Fj.png)

## Update:

I inserted the following code

```
<?php
          global $product;
         $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

        foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
        {
          echo $image_link = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id  );
        }
        ?>
```

Which shows the images expected. This isn't a solution however, as the images need to change the main displayed image when clicked.

## Update 2:

I've downgraded WP to match the original site and now receive this error above the empty images:

**Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs...\themes\branchy\woocommerce\single-product.php**

Which is in the code pasted above.

## Update 3:

upgraded wordpress on original site (lucky it hasn't vanished yet) and images still work there correctly

Comment: When you say "adding a new image results in the same problem." what do you mean by that? Do you mean that uploading a new image into the new site does not fix the issue? I might have some ideas if you can answer that.

Comment: @Shawn I mean if I go to edit or create new product, upload a new image and add it to the product's gallery, it results in the same behavior: It shows in the edit product gallery panel, but shows empty image placeholder (as shown in attached image) on the page. I can insert the images into the page itself and they show up. It does show the correct QTY of image placeholders, if that helps.

Comment: We might need to coordinate a way to jump onto a StackOverflow chat to work through some issues it might be. First did you use the wordpress import/export tool to move the site? It might be some bad references in the DB now but depends. For now, attempt to resave permalinks just to make sure this is not an issue with post paths. Also please use an inspect element tool to see if the browser console is throwing any errors as to http or https (basically mixed-content). As a solution to try as well is a thumbnail rebuilding plugin such as "Ajax Thumbnail Rebuild" if the other solutions didnt work.

Comment: @Shawn thankyou for your thoughts :) wow I never even knew Stack overflow has chat. I used the wordpress import/export tool to move the site initially, though later I tried moving DB again with All-in-One WP Migration plugin, which worked if didn't try to get everything at once. I did see elsewhere to try resaving permalinks which made no difference. I just tried Ajax Thumbnail Rebuild which does not appear to help. 
The images do appear if I use a basic wp_get_attached_image (see edit on original question) so the images certainly seem to be where they are supposed to be.

Comment: When I use the inspect tool, what should I be looking for? I'm used to using this for html/css but not the console section.
Everything in console seems to start with http:// but there is a TypeError: m is undefined and a couple of depreciated warnings: getAttributeNode() and getPreventDefault()

Comment: If you can use "inspect element" item which lets you click on an element in the page and click on the broken images. This should show you the image path. You want to verify that the url is correct. As another question did you change Wordpress versions on migration? Meaning did you move from an older version to a newer one? Wordpress 4.3 split terms and taxonomies. More debugging info will help alot. As one last thing checking PHP error logs would be helpful, as they might show any fatals. As to the page template those sound like theme javascript errors which could be a culprit as well.

Comment: How old or when was the last time the theme was updated?

Comment: As shown in the Qn, the broken images show an empty path `(<a data-full=""><img src="")`. The template is a custom template made by previous developer. It appears to be a modified version of twentyfourteen but if I understand correctly how child themes work, it isn't a child theme (the twentyfourteen theme is not installed on the site). The version of Wordpress on the original site is 4.2.5. The version I'm working with is 4.3.1. Can I downgrade it? I'm looking at C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log, but I cannot see any fatal errors I haven't caused myself when making changes while experimenting.

Comment: Going to try downgrading wordpress, will note if it helps or not!

Comment: After downgrading WP to the same version as the original site, I have the following error: **Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\themes\branchy\woocommerce\single-product.php** The argument referenced is part of the code I've been looking at in original Qn

Comment: Just as a proof of concept, can you upgrade the wordpress version on the original site and see if the images are broken? If this breaks you then we know the template needs to update, if the images still work then we need to consider that there is some sort of custom code that might be using some different path or something, in which case we might want to paste that code. If we can remove some variables then that is helpful.

Comment: Ok, upgrading the original went smoothly and everything still works ok. Any tips on how to track down the probably code in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure why the problem was occurring in the first place but it may have been failing to connect to the database?

Having noted that the mysql api used in the original code was depreciated, I rebuilt the piece of code using mysqli instead.

After some difficulty I managed to figure out how to use $wpdb instead of putting the connection string into the code (thanks mostly to [this article](http://clivern.com/working-with-wordpress-wpdb-object/))

```
<!-- first image is viewable to start -->
       <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
       </div>
       <div class="previews">
       <?php 
       global $wpdb;
       $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

       foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
          $sql="SELECT guid FROM wp_1posts WHERE ID = ".$attachment_id;
          $row=$wpdb->get_row($sql);
       ?>
       <a data-full="<?php echo $row->guid;?>"><img src="<?php echo $row->guid;?>" width="56" height="58" /></a>
```

Main thing is, it's working!

Thanks @Shawn for helping me troubleshoot :)

Comment: Glad to see you got this working. The mysql object was deprecated in php 5.5 and is removed in php 7. Not sure why your connection would have been failing to connect unless your configs were different. As per some trac ticketing on wordpress it looks like they squash warnings on mysql objects but have been working to remove these for a few years so you can debug. Considering that you got this working on the WP db instance I would have to assume that the configs were different on the installs. This seems validated by the upgrade on the old system worked but the migration did not.

Comment: Now that you are using the wpdb object instantiated by wordpress itself it knows where to find the tables.

Comment: I was rather pleased to get it working but now Wordpress has updated and introduced a new bug, something to do with srcset for responsive images... I may be posting a new question about that one... But I'll wait and deal with that after Christmas! lol

Comment: Thats a known issue I am having as well. It started as an issue on 4.3. You can view it here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34109